# Playing audio files from object array in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, audio

I'm working on making an object to wrap controls around instances of html5 audio elements. For testing, I've made an object like this (simplified for readability)..

```
function AudioObject(audio) {
    var innerAudio = audio;

    this.Play = function () {
        innerAudio.play()
    }
}
```

And I have an array holding instances of this AudioObject.

```
var AudioObjects = [];
```

Then, when creating new AudioObjects, I add them to the array. I have a function that plays the AudioObjects with delays so they play in sequence. Something like this:

```
var audioObj = new AudioObject(audio);
AudioObjects.push(audioObj);
....
....
var delay = 0;
$.each(AudioObjects, function(iterator, obj) {
    setTimeout(obj.Play, delay);
    delay = delay + 3000;
}
```

When there is just one audio file, it plays correctly, but once I add more AudioObjects, each one in the array has their innerAudio variable set to the latest created Audio element. I can play each one individually from the html. I've debugged on creation and I can see it's setting the right audio, but after being pushed to the array, the objects in the array all get switched to the latest innerAudio.

Am I not instantiating my objects correctly? I've made [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3AGc/) to experiment with alerting text, and it doesn't seem to have the issues I'm experiencing.

Update: I think I found my issue. This is how I thought you write a "public" and a "private" function inside of an object.

```
function Thing(test) {
    var thingTest = test;

    // Public function
    this.PublicTest = function () {
        setTimeout(Test, 1000);
    }

    // Private function
    PrivateTest = function () {
       alert(thingTest);
    }
}
```

This is essentially how my code was structured, but the "private" function has a different scope than the public one. I double-checked my array, and it was actually saving the right audioObject with the correct audio source, but when running the function that calls the "private" function, it calls the wrong audio file.

I've updated [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3AGc/) to show what's happening. I thought it would alert "test1" then "test2" but it alerts "test2" twice.

Update 2: For the record, changing the private function to this fixed the problem:

```
function Play() {   // <<< That's all I had to change!
    innerAudio.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you create unique aduio object for each audio wrapper?

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'src';

var audioObj = new AudioObject(audio);
AudioObjects.push(audioObj);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am. This is the line that is making the new AudioObject..

    var recObj = new AudioObject(0, audio.duration, audio);

At the point that the object is made, "audio" is referring to a different src than the AudioObject in my AudioObjects array. It's once I push this new object that the one in the array changes.

Comment: Ah! I found my problem!! I'm updating my original post.